# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to run a selenium test but getting the above error. I think this is a compatibility issue but I am not sure as I have very basic knowledge of selenium. My geckodriver version is 0.31.0 and firefox browser version is 100 and selenium version is selenium == 4.1.0. Any idea how I can fix this?

This is my conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as ff_service

    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver_path = ff_service(r"/usr/bin/geckodriver")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_path,options = options)  #getting error at this line
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: According to the compatibility chart provided here (https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html), your driver versio 0.31.0 should work properly with the browser version 100.
Could you provide the code that you wrote?

Comment: yes exactly. Sure, i will add my code in the question.

Comment: I have seen examples using [this] (https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/115596/selenium.webdriver.FirefoxOptions)